# update query changing value in multiple columns

Tags: php, sql

How can I write a query to change a value in multiple columns where there is a specific value? I want to update a table: look through 40 columns (q1-q40) if the value in that column is -1 then change that to -999 for all rows. Do i still have to list cases for each column or is there an easier way?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to express your logic for all 40 columns.  There is no syntax for generalising an expression across multiple columns.

Comment: Fix your data structure!  Having multiple columns distinguished by a number is usually a sign of poor data design.  You should probably have another table with one row per "entity" and per "q" value.

Comment: Thank you MatBailie and Thank you Gordon Linoff.  I see, I will be looking at data structure and design videos tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't escape the long winded approach.

If I understand your requirement, it would be something like...

```
UPDATE
  table
SET
  col00 = CASE WHEN col00 = -1 THEN -999 ELSE col00 END,
  col01 = CASE WHEN col01 = -1 THEN -999 ELSE col01 END,
  col02 = CASE WHEN col02 = -1 THEN -999 ELSE col02 END,
  ...
  col37 = CASE WHEN col37 = -1 THEN -999 ELSE col37 END,
  col38 = CASE WHEN col38 = -1 THEN -999 ELSE col38 END,
  col39 = CASE WHEN col39 = -1 THEN -999 ELSE col39 END
WHERE
  -1 IN (col00, col01, col02, ... col37, col38, col39)
```

Or 40 straight forward updates...

This is a good example of when code that writes SQL is a useful approach.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the update statement. Here is what will need to do:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET q1 = -999, q2 = -999, q3= -999 etc..... q40 = -999 
WHERE q1 = -1, q2 = -1, q3= -1 etc...... q40 = -1;
```

And this will update the rows that you need, though will be a pain. I updated since you clarified your question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!